# Android NDK r10c build error for arm64-v8a: No such file or directory #include <sha1.h>

Tags: android, android-ndk, sha1, arm64

I have a native C code, which calculates a SHA1 digest. It compiled without problems with NDK r10b. But I've got this error with NDK r10c:

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : my-library <= my-library-jni.c 
{PATH_TO_THE_FILE}/my-library-jni.c:3:18: fatal error: sha1.h: 
 No such file or directory
 #include <sha1.h>
```

I'm updating to NDK r10c to compile for 64-bit platforms. It seems that 64-bit headers do not include sha1.h. Why? And how can I fix it? Should I find some C implementation of SHA1 and include it in my project?

**Edit**

I ended up using the code from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/c/liboauth/src/sha1.c. 
It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you didn't try building in 64 bit mode with NDK r10b, because I don't find the sha1.h header there for arm64-v8a either.

It seems that the SHA1 support exposed previously wasn't really intended - it wasn't really mentioned anywhere in the documentation and the "Stable APIs" documentation doesn't mention it either (and I guess it can't be assumed to be part of the C library itself even though technically it was). The libc.so that you link to in 32 bit mode also includes MD5 functions, which aren't exposed in the headers at all, which makes it all seem even more unintended/unplanned.

Even if it wasn't originally intended, they've kept it for compatibility in 32 bit mode, but chose to remove such unintended baggage in 64 bit mode.

Some commit links to clarify:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/c82c0b7e07
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/69c6d8419%5E%21/

Yes, your solution is to find an existing C implementation of SHA1 (luckily there are many different ones available under a varity of licenses) and include it instead. Most of them have quite similar or almost identical APIs.